# Coming as a Spouse to Denmark

Tags: taxes, denmark

My wife has come to Denmark to work for 2-3 years. I would like to apply to come here as a spouse but would still like to retain my job in Singapore as I am allowed to work from anywhere in the world. Wondering if that would be possible? Not sure if anyone knows how the taxes would work

Comment: What is your wife's nationality?  If not EU/EEA, what is her immigration status?  What is your nationality?

Comment: We are both Singaporean. She has a residence and work permit to work in Denmark